# I want to show a notification when a social network app is open

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am working on a small project and I want to know if I can catch an event when sertain apps are open.

For example, the user opens reddit, then my app gives him a notification.

Is that possible? I am not an expert with android OS stuff.

(If it is possible I can do it with a multiplatform framework like flutter?)

Answer (score 1):

The ways to interact with other apps are limited and even more restricted when you're about to find out what other apps are doing on the phone.

On Android, you could try to write an `AccessibilityService` which can get the app that is currently running and post a notification then.

I don't think this is possible on multiplatform apps, esp. I don't think Apple allows this on iOS.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, I am researching and there is no easy way to use AccessibilityService in multiplatform frameworks. But it is great anyway. ty

I am going to start working and if everything goes ok I will accept this answer.